# Importing external JUnit5 reports into IntelliJ: Test framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5

I need to import JUnit5 integration test report files generated with Maven Failsafe plugin from an external Maven run into IntelliJ.

I use **Run > Import tests from file** and select the .xml file generated by the Failsafe plugin.

The file looks about as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/xsd/failsafe-test-report-3.0.xsd" version="3.0" name="com.maihiro.maitour.odata.account.CorporateAccountUUIDRepositoryIT" time="2.635" tests="1" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
    <property name="gopherProxySet" value="false"/>
    <property name="awt.toolkit" value="sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit"/>
    <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io"/>
    <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value=""/>
    <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    [...]
    <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeBig"/>
    <property name="java.class.version" value="52.0"/>
  </properties>
  <testcase name="redacted" classname="com.example.RedactedTest" time="2.616"/>
</testsuite>
```

However in the Run view, IntelliJ just gives me the message "Test framework quit unexpectedly". There is nothing in the Run console or in the IntelliJ debug log.

How can I find out why IntelliJ won't import the file?

Comment: What do you mean by importing a report into IntelliJ? A report is a report nothing which can be executed? Can you please describe more in detail what you exactly like to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html#import-test-results

Comment: Import from file means having an external jar which contains the tests ... not a report...

Comment: No, that's not what is meant here. It's test results from a previous test run, exported to an XML file, which can then be re-imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself: It's not possible since Maven test reports have a different format than expected by IntelliJ.

IntelliJ can only import test reports that have been exported from tests run in IntelliJ.

Comment: The reports are html / xml reports have never been intended for such kind of thing. Create a test-jar which could be what you might need.. I don't understand why you need the tests from a different project... you could define a dependency and run surefire/failsafe to run those tests...

Comment: It's not about tests from a different project ... it's tests from the same project that have been run with plain Maven outside of IntelliJ. Viewing them in IntelliJ would be a lot more convenient than scrolling through the pain text or XML output that Maven produces, so I thought I could import the test result files into IntelliJ. IntelliJ supports importing previous test results but unfortunately it uses its own format that is not compatible with the Maven output format.